# How to create DAG (Graph) with different shapes using NGX-Graph

Tags: angular, directed-acyclic-graphs, ngx-charts

I want to create graph with custom node shapes and custom colors. I also want to have the edges with labels on them. How can I do this using NGX-Graph (https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/)

Eg[image: here is the sample of the graph what I want to build.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own template for the node and customize it however you want:

```html
<ngx-graph [legend]="false" [links]="graph.links" [scheme]="colorScheme" [nodes]="graph.nodes" [nodeWidth]="70" [nodeHeight]="70" [orientation]="'LR'" [curve]="curve">
  <ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
    <svg:g class="node">
      <svg:rect [attr.width]="node.width" [attr.height]="node.height" stroke="#3d465a" fill="#262C38" stroke-width="2" rx="15" ry="15" />
      <svg:rect [attr.width]="node.width - 10" [attr.height]="node.height - 10" [attr.fill]="node.options.color" rx="10" ry="10" x="5" y="5" />
      <svg:text class="node-type" alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="16" [attr.y]="15">
        {{node.type}}
      </svg:text>
      <svg:image alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="(node.width / 2) - 16" [attr.y]="25" [attr.width]="32" [attr.height]="32" [attr.xlink:href]="getImageForNode(node)" />
      <svg:text class="node-label" alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="(node.width / 2) - ((node.label.length * 5) / 2)" [attr.y]="85">
        {{node.label}}
      </svg:text>
    </svg:g>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-graph>
```

You have access to the node data in that template, so you can draw different shapes based on the node's properties.

Comment: If I understand it correctly what you meant is having structure like  
`<ngx-graph>  
<ng-template #template1>  
</ng-template>  
<ng-template #template2>  
</ng-template>  
</ngx-graph>`    
  
How can I use link to different nodes in the graph to render different shapes?

Comment: Do you have ngx-graph documentation link?